# Java Client Server, Multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client, server

I am currently coding a client-server JAVA application and I'm kind of stuck. I searched on the net to find some helpful code. I found this sample (I want to use it when I am waiting for a connection) but I don't really understand what this code is suppose to be doing, could someone out there help out? :)

```
Executor threadpool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(maxClients);
```

Comment: To wait client requests to open a connection, you need one thread which in a loop calls to serversockect.accept(). You need not threadpool. To wait message from the client after connection is opened, you can use thread pool, but it is more complex than using a separate thread per client, and when maxClients is surpassed, extra client connections would be accepted but not handled. So don't use thread pool in the prototype version of your server.

Comment: your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588476/multithreading-socket-communication-client-server

Answer (score 0):

The [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface and the [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) Factory help you use ThreadPools.

In your case: You want to handle incoming client connection concurrently. So you need a Thread for each. So submitting a Task to an Executor is a convenient way to not be bothered with Thread creation etc.

So the line

```
Executor threadpool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(maxClients);
```

declares `threadpool` to be an Executor ( that Tasks can be submitted to later on ) but you don't care which of the implementations. The right side of the "=" then uses the Factory to retrieve an instance of one of the implementations of Executor. In this case it is a `ScheduledThreadPool` with at least `maxClients` Threads waiting for new Tasks.

In the code it will probably used like

```
threadpool.execute( new ClientHandler(socket) );
```

where ClientHandler is some helperclass implementing Runnable, that handles IO with the Client.